# What does Latin "et alios" mean?

Tags: meaning, latin

As I learned from Wiktionary site, there are exists these Latin phrases:

- [et alii](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_alii) - And others; used of men or boys, or groups of mixed gender; masculine plural
- [et aliae](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_aliae) - And others; used of women or girls; feminine plural
- [et alios](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_alios) - And others; used of people, unless exclusively of female gender
- [et alia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_alia) - And others; used of things; neuter plural.

Also, a note (actually, a quote) about **et alii** and it's alternatives:

> **Alii** is masculine, so it can be used for men, or groups of men and women; the feminine, **et aliae**, is appropriate when the "others" are all female; but as with many loanwords, interlingual use (such as in reference lists) is often invariable. **Et alia** is neuter plural and thus in Latin text is properly used only for inanimate, genderless objects, but some use it as a gender-neutral alternative.
>
> - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(E)#et_alii

My actual question is about **et alios**. As non-native English speaker, I can't understand the definition mentioned above ("used of people, unless exclusively of female gender"). What does it actually mean?

---

Edit:

"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the meaning of a phrase in Latin, not English." - Mark Beadles

@Mark Beadles I'm actually want to understand the meaning of English phrase: "used of people, unless exclusively of female gender". This "unless exclusively" is something what I can't understand. – jsv

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the meaning of a phrase in Latin, not English.

Comment: As as BrE speaker I have only seen *et alia* used, obviously not in common parlance, only in documents.

Comment: @Mark Beadles I'm actually want to understand the meaning of English phrase: "used of people, unless exclusively of female gender". This "unless exclusively" is something what I can't understand.

Comment: This is where et. al. comes from (which I happen to use occasionally).

Comment: The "unless exclusively of female gender" means "unless every single one of these people is female".

Comment: @jsv That certainly isn't what you wrote in your title.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Well, I will edit the title.

Comment: @MarkBeadles It is part of English, in the sense that in its abbreviated form (‘et al.) it was very common.  It was on the covers of many a jazz album.  Latin tags appear in historical documents in the law and elsewhere.

Comment: @MarkBeadles '_Et al_' or '_et alia_' is certainly part of English usage as a commandeered word. And since '_et al_' is non-specific I think it to be quite justifiable to examine the four words above in enquiry.

Comment: There are still scholars who, for whatever reason, do not abbreviate to et al. That the abbreviation is never italicized tells you that, as Latin as they may be, the unabbreviated forms are English words. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=et+alia%2Cet+alios%2Cet+alii&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cet%20alia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cet%20alios%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cet%20alii%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @KarlG Thanks, very interesting. It seems that prior to 1950, _et alia_ was a preferable form. After 1950, the preferable form is _et alii_.

Comment: WIktionary has confused many things here, including conflating Latin use of gender with that of English. These are not the same.

Comment: @jsv The overwhelming preference in both legal and academic contexts is the abbreviation et al. Stick that in the NGram and all the gendered and declined Latin forms will be hugging the bottom.

Comment: I've nominated this for reopening, as the OP has made it clear that the question is not about the Latin phrase, but about the meaning of an English phrase used to define it. Possibly  it should be moved to ELL.

Comment: @ColinFine Also, as I discovered today there exists latin.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Et alios*** is in the (masculine plural) accusative case in Latin, which is used when e.g. the "others" are the **object** in a sentence. So you could use it when the "others" are the object in an English sentence; but this is not normally done in English: we normally use the nominative ("subject") case of foreign words in an English sentence no matter whether they're subject or object. The other forms in your question are all nominatives, so you can always use those. The meaning of *alios* (masculine plural accusative) is exactly the same as *alii* (masculine plural nominative) except for the different cases.

P.S. The use of *et alia* (neuter plural) as a "gender-neutral alternative" is ill advised. It is like the English word *it*, only used for things, and not for people.

Comment: Of course, I upvoted. Well, I understand it's very thoughtful answer. Now I need some time to read about objects and subjects in English.

Comment: @jsv: the idea of using different word forms for objects and subjects (except for pronouns) is completely foreign to English speakers ... I suspect it's only people who know something about languages where this is done who would even consider using the accusative case *et alios* rather than *et alii* or *et aliae*.

Comment: @PeterShor If I can, I would upvote your comment too. :-) So, as I understand from your words, if I want to stay grammatically correct (from both English and Latin points of view), I should avoid of using _et alios_ in English text?

Comment: If you used *et alios*, you might actually be correct from the Latin point of view. But if you're writing in English, that's beside the point. Nobody uses *deum ex machina* in English, even when that would be correct in Latin.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks, I understand. So, when we want to use some form for mixed group of men and women, we have a choice between _et alii_ and _et alia_ (used of things). The first isn't really gender-neutral (it's more about the men), but the second isn't actually correct in traditional Latin and used in modern English as "a new sense in the old written word"? So, from grammatical point of view, we should stay with _et alii_?

Comment: @PeterShor: You're simplifying the issue. I believe Fowler had a nice overview of the issue in one of his books. I believe my answer has the right 'answer': *but this is not normally done in English: we normally use the nominative ("subject") case of foreign words in an English sentence no matter whether they're subject or object.* Nevertheless, there is some merit in using the accusative (or other cases) for pedants and language enthusiasts.

Comment: @Cerberus So, as I understand, for a group consisting of both men and women it will be the best to use _et alii_? (I mean, when we don't want to use an abbreviated form _et al._)

Comment: @Cerberus: my reply wasn't directed at you but at jsv, whose comment seemed to indicate he was considering using *et alios*. I don't think there's anything wrong with your answer.

Comment: @jsv: Yes, exactly!

Comment: @PeterShor: Ah, phew!